# Could Emacs be used to login via 2FA token?

Tags: emacs, tramp

I wanted to login to a system which uses 2FA token authentication. Unfortunately Emacs does not seem to prompt for the 2FA token and just hangs there until it reaches a timeout call. The ssh mechanism is very simple; public IP, username and key. Once it connects the prompt  is also quite standard "Enter your 2FA token:"

Is there anything I need to do/configure in Emacs to be able to obtain the 2FA prompt and introduce the token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to use Tramp. Since Tramp 2.5 (integrated in Emacs 28), it supports the user option `tramp-security-key-confirm-regexp`. Please configure it accordingly.

In case it still doesn't work, set `tramp-verbose` to 6, and contact the mailing list `tramp-devel@gnu.org`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about authenticating with a security key, like a FIDO2 key, when opening a remote file via Tramp, .... It works for me.  I use Emacs 28.2 running on Windows 10.

Steps, roughly:

1. open a ssh session to the remote host using an existing authorized key.
   You can do this in emacs with a tramp url. I used `/sshx:remotehost:/home` .
2. upgrade Windows to OpenSSH v9.2.2.0 or some version that supports security keys. The builtin OpenSSH, available in `c:\windows\system32\openssh`, is version 8.1p1, which is not sufficient, it does not support security keys. When you "upgrade" really you're installing a new version of OpenSSH. It will appear in `c:\progra~1\OpenSSH`. You'll need to take care to use the proper version of OpenSSH from now on.
3. In a powershell terminal, create a keypair via

   ```
   c:\progra~1\OpenSSH\ssh-keygen -t ecdsa-sk -f ~/.ssh/sk-1
   ```
4. Modify the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote host, to accept only
   the public key you just generated. You can do this via the previously opened
   tramp session.
5. Modify the `tramp-methods` in emacs to use the new `ssh.exe`, like this:

   ```
   (setf
    (car (alist-get "sshx" tramp-methods nil nil #'equal))
    '(tramp-login-program "C:/Progra~1/OpenSSH/ssh.exe"))
   ```
6. close out tramp sessions.  Re-open the same tramp filespec.  See the challenge for the Security Key.  Touch the key.
   See it work.  Rejoice.